# Is there a per country estimation of the GDP drop due to COVID?

Tags: gdp, covid-19-crisis

I've been looking around for some per-country estimation of the expected GDP drop due to the COVID pandemic.

I've found [this answer](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/34622/29972) in this site but it only mentions a few countries. I understand not all countries will have such an estimation, but maybe for the G20 or similar groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some cross-country studies but not that many of them yet. For example, [Maliszewska, M., Mattoo, A., & Van Der Mensbrugghe, D. (2020)](https://elibrary.worldbank.org/doi/abs/10.1596/1813-9450-9211) from world bank provide some cross-country estimates of the cumulative effect of covid-19 for various countries and regions across the world. Their estimated cumulative effect of covid on GDP (measured as deviation from their benchmark) is shown below.

[image]

However, I would advise to take these results with a pinch of salt. These are preliminary estimates that were published in April and better ones will be fore sure forthcoming in near future.

Comment: Thank you very much! What does the "amplified" colum mean?

Comment: @Gabriel those are different scenarios of how bad the pandemic will be - amplified is a scenario under which pandemic will be worse than in the “standard” pandemic scenario in first column. Authors also explain in greater detail how the scenarios differ in the paper itself